# Add javascript file at the end of the script block

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i am using cakephp 3.7 and i load few .js file in my default.ctp layout. The problems comes when i try to add other .js in my view. These js files are added at the beginning of the js file list.
I do echo $this->fetch('script'); to print that block.

For example, i am using jquery, i load this library in default.ctp because i use it  everywhere, the problem is that view js are loaded before jquery so i cannot use `$`

how can i "append" to script block, inside an action's view?
Thanks

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout put (before < /head> if you wish) 
 $this->fetch('my_head_script') 
, then in your view use 
$this->Html->script("jquery.js",['block' => 'my_head_script']);

Answer (score 0):

Did You use script blocks, described here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-inline-javascript-blocks?

Comment: no, i have used $this->Html->script(); with 'block' => true i correctly see the .js files but at the top of that list when i do echo $this->fetch('script')